# What part of speech is “worth”?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, worth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the lexical class of the word 'worth' when used in a sentence like “Is this apple worth $3?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/what-is-the-lexical-class-of-the-word-worth-when-used-in-a-sentence-like-is-t)

In a sentence like the following:

> The knight’s statue had a tale worth telling.

What is *worth*?  I wanted to identify it a preposition, showing relation between *tale* and *telling*.

Comment: This is actually a tough question. The [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/worth) says "The modern adjectival senses of worth compare two noun phrases, prompting some sources to classify the word as a preposition. Most, however, list it an adjective, some with notes like 'governing a noun with prepositional force.' Fowler's Modern English Usage says, 'the adjective worth requires what is most easily described as an object.'"

Comment: See http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=worth&tbs=dfn:1 Adjective # 2 & 3.  The tale is worth being told.

Comment: Would someone say "worth" is a preposition in "That isn't worth much"?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 5):

It is actually an adjective.  The OED has a note about it:

> Almost always (now only) in predicative use, or following the sb. as part of a qualifying phrase.

I can see why you would think of it as a preposition, in that it seems to take an object.

- That cow is worth five hundred dollars to me.

When used following its “object”, it acts as a noun with a possessive in front of it — or you might think of it as a postposition that takes a genitive.

- I’d like ten dollars’ worth, please.

It’s a very old word.  The OED’s second citation for it is from the 7<sup>th</sup> century:

> - A. 695 *Laws Ine* lviii, ― Oxan horn bið x. pæninga weorð

Which (I presume) means something like “Oxen horn be-eth 10 pennies worth”. By the time Old English had creoled into Middle English, we see the now-familiar formula:

> - C. 1350 *Athelston* 391 ― Now is my goode hors forlorn,··He was wurþ an hundryd pounde.

If someone asked how much something was *valued*, you would think of *valued* as an adjective.  They can similarly ask how much something is *worth*, so it stands to reason that *worth* is also an adjective.  But yes, it is weird.

One upon a time there was an adjective ***wurthe***, meaning *worthy*, which eventually merged with *worth*.  The OED writes:

> OE. *wierðe, wyrðe,* etc., a derivative from *weorþ* worth sb.1 or a. In OE. and early southern ME. texts distinguishable from **worth** a., but subsequently merged with it.

The most legible citation is this:

> - C. 1325 *Chron. Eng.* 741 in Ritson Metr. Rom. II. 301 ― Afterward, ase he wes wurthe,··An abbot him remue wolde.

*Wurthe* also meant merited or deserved, as in this citation:

> - A. 1225 *Ancr. R.* 138 ― We moten þauh don him wo, ase hit is ofte wel wurðe.

It is not surprising that it merged with *worth*.

A more clearly adjectival use is the now archaic:

> - 1871 B. Taylor *Faust* II. ii. ii. 148 ― Little worth is woman’s beauty, So oft an image dumb we see.

Comment: I'm not convinced: "He had a tale worth/*valued telling?"

Comment: @MarkBeadles That looks like a different meaning of the same word. That kind of "worth" means "worthy of" instead of "having a value of" - I would say that the word *worth* in "The apples are worth $2" has a different definition than *worth* in "a tale worth telling."  It wouldn't work to say, "a tale having a value of telling/a tale valued telling," but it also wouldn't work to say, "The apples are worthy of $2."

Answer (score 5):

I have seen some authorities (including the [CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/)) put *worth* in a class of words called **marginal prepositions**. These words can be used mostly like prepositions, but "[have affinities with other word classes](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/preps/marginal.htm)"; usually they come from other parts of speech that have undergone some [grammaticalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization). This characterization is admittedly vague, but the number of words in the class is small, and it has been observed that "Their occurrence is tightly constrained by grammatical and lexical factors." ([Rankin and Schiftner, 2009](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/publications/CL2009/145_FullPaper.do))

Other marginal prepositions in English include:

> *following, concerning, considering, excluding, given, granted, pending, worth, minus, plus, instead of*

Other languages sometimes have marginal prepositions too. Generally they seem to be **words that are derived from other parts of speech and are in the process of becoming regular prepositions**.

Answer (score 5):

Here's [a paper](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) about the relative grammar and meaning of *value, worth, cost,* and *price*.

What it says (on p.391) about the grammatical category of *worth* is:

> ".. the categorial status of *worth* is a matter of some dispute. It has variously been claimed to be a preposition and an adjective (cf Maling 1983 and McCawley 1985). If it is a preposition, then it must have a homophonous derived noun, since phrases like *the worth of the book* are common enough. On the other hand, if it is an adjective, then it must be **transitive**, since it has a complement; this is surely unusual -- or even impossible, according to some theories of grammatical categories. I will have nothing to say about the categorial status of *worth* here, since the matter is irrelevant to its meaning; let it stand that no matter what category *worth* may belong to, it is an atypical example of the category."

---

- Heny, Frank; and Richards, Barry (eds). 1983. *Linguistic Categories: Auxiliaries and related puzzles* (2 Vols). Dordrech: Reidel.
- Maling, Joan. 1983. "Transitive adjectives: A case of categorial reanalysis." In Heny and Richards 1983.
- McCawley, James D. 1985. Review article on Heny and Richards (eds) 1983. In *Language,* vol 61, pp 849-62.

Comment: I also sometimes wonder whether *like* is a preposition in “there aren’t many people like him”, since it takes a complement there.  But then you realize it admits modifiers of degree, which is a funny thing to apply to a preposition. I guess some things can be more inside the house than others are, but it still seems odd.

Comment: As Sapir put it, all grammars leak. POS are just a guide, and there will always be cases that fall between the stools. Language is alive, after all, and variation is the key to surviving evolution.

Answer (score -2):

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230380?rskey=Hn6Coy&result=4#eid) says that *worth* is a [predicative expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_%28verb%29) - part of a clause predicate.

When the *worth* is relative to a person, the dative of that persion is invoked.  In this such cases of direct or indirect questions, *worth* is an [indefinite article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_article#Indefinite_article)

Comment: I get downvoted for **citing a dictionary**?

Comment: Is the indefinite article statement also a part of the citation?

Comment: @musiphil *Yes*, OED indicates that it is an indefinite article.