# Why can we say “worth more than” but not “expensive more than”?

Tags: adjectives, comparisons, worth

Why can we say:

> It is worth more than. . . .

but not:

> It is expensive more than. . . .

It’s the position of *more* which I find so confusing.

Also, is *worth* an adjective in both these cases?

Comment: Related: [What is the lexical class of the word 'worth' when used in a sentence like “Is this apple worth $3?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15982)

Comment: The simple answer is that *expensive* is an adjective and *worth* is not: we don't say "That's worth!" or "a worth watch" as we say "That's expensive!" or "an expensive watch". What exactly *worth* **is** is beyond me; it started as a noun; perhaps it's a preposition, as some answers in @tchrist's link suggest (but that seems very far-fetched to me). I'd call it, here at least, a component of a verbal phrase "to be worth", meaning "to cost"; which is a fancy way of saying It Is What It Is.

Comment: @StoneyB This is actually a better link: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83946/2085

Comment: @tchrist  A transitive adjective. Wow! I love this language. Colin, the question will probably be closed as an Exact Duplicate; but thank you for raising it. I don't know if you learned anything useful, but I did.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 12):

*Expensive* is behaving as a typical adjective, which are only modified by preceding degree words, e.g.

> It was more expensive than...
>   It was more sudden than...
>   It was more amazing than...

If we pretend for a moment that *is worth* was a verb, we could compare it with some other verbs of measuring activites, e.g.

> It weighs more than...
>   The room seats more people than...
>   It measures more than...
>   It costs more than...

The phrase *is worth* behaves likes a stative verb. The only other comparable phrase I can think of is *[be] up/down* as in:

> The Lions are down three points.
>   The Lions are up more than the Bears were up at this point last week.

If *worth* is an adjective, then it is one which is almost always restricted to being a predicative adjective. This is how *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED) describes it, noting that it is used

> Almost always (now only) in predicative use, or following the n. as part of a qualifying phrase.

What is interesting is that although an expression like

> *Gold is more worth than silver.

with a preceding degree word, would be usually considered ungrammatical, there are several attestations listed in OED of exactly such a usage (where a degree word precedes *worth*) from the Early Modern English period:

> 1568   Newe Comedie Jacob & Esau ii. iv. C iv b,   Ah sir, when one is hungry, good meat is much worth.
>   1581   G. Pettie tr. S. Guazzo Ciuile Conuersat. (1586) iii. 138   It may rightly be saide..that the feathers are more worth then the byrde.
>   1615   W. Lawson Country Housewifes Garden (1626) 6   Fruit blown vnripe, are small worth.

I'd say *worth* is an unusual word, and has only become more unusual in recent history.

Answer (score 5):

*Worth* is a difficult word.

[For example](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf)

> "The categorial status of *worth* is a matter of some dispute. It has variously been
>   claimed to be a preposition and an adjective (cf. Maling 1983 and McCawley 1985). If it is a preposition, then it must have a homophonous derived noun, since phrases like *the worth of the book* are common enough. On the other hand, if it is an adjective, then it must be **transitive**, since it has a complement; this is surely unusual -- or even impossible, according to some theories of grammatical categories.
>
> "Let it stand that no matter what category *worth* may belong to, it is an atypical 
>   example of the category."

In this particular case, *worth* is behaving transitively, since it has a complement with a comparative construction: *more than . . . .*

*Expensive*, on the other hand, is an ordinary adjective and has to be either a predicate adjective

- *That necklace is more expensive than she can afford.*

or an attributive adjective

- *She didn't buy that expensive necklace.*

And the comparative construction places adjectives **after** *more*, not before *more*.

Comment: As @jlovegren says, usage has [changed relatively recently](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+worth+than&year_start=1790&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=). I must admit that, [A man is of more worth than a beast](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0O09AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22more+worth+than%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MOrPULy0DLHs0gXn2IC4Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22more%20worth%20than%22&f=false) sounds a bit Victorian, but only a bit. Of course, without the *"of"* it would sound a *lot* more Victorian.