# How does "The proposal is worth considering" contain an adverbial objective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs

An adverbial objective a noun that functions as an adverb.

Often, the noun, as an adverb, modifies a verb, for example, "He went home". I understand "Home", here, as being the adverbial objective, for it expresses a relation of place.

In the titular sentence, however, I don't understand what the adverbial objective is. Is it supposed to be "considering" or "worth considering"?

Comment: Who said there's an "adverbial objective" in your title?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the lexical class of the word 'worth' when used in a sentence like "Is this apple worth $3?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/what-is-the-lexical-class-of-the-word-worth-when-used-in-a-sentence-like-is-t) Or [What part of speech is 'worth'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83940/what-part-of-speech-is-worth)?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 1):

***Worth*** is somewhat a controversial word, there is a dispute about it being an adjective or a preposition (especially in sentences like *It is worth two dollars*).  McCawley, R. Hyddleston and G. Pullum call it an adjective.

I don't see any NOUN in your sentence that functions as an adverb modifying a verb.
In

> The proposal is *worth* *considering*.

H&P say that *worth* is an adjective functioning as a predicate, while *considering* is a hollow gerund-participial that functions as a complement of the adjective *worth*. (See T*he Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,* pp. 546 and 607)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "adverbial objective"

In *“He went home”*  “Home” is an uncountable noun acting as the adverbial complement of “went” (sometimes called a dative, as in *“He went *to* home."*)

In *“The proposal is worth considering”*, *“worth considering”* is an adjectival phrase and a complement.

**Considering** is a gerund, (*“The proposal is worth **your/his/our, etc.** considering”*) and could be substituted for *“consideration”*.

**Worth** takes on a prepositional function: compare

*“The proposal is {**under** consideration}”.*

*“The proposal is {**worth** considering}”*

Under the entry for “**worth** *adj*.” in the OED is the comment:

> *“Chiefly (and now only) in predicative use, or following a noun as part of a qualifying phrase. In modern English* worth *is non-gradable **and sometimes regarded as a preposition.***
> I. Having a specified value.