# "What's it worth"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, worth

Recently I encountered the sentence "What's it worth?" in a book.

I cannot understand the structure of this sentence.

From my perspective, ["worth" means "value"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worth) in this sentence. But I would expect to see "What is ITS worth?"

Could you please help me in understanding the structure of this sentence?

Comment: Why is it a noun, not an adjective?

Comment: "What is it worth?" is perfectly logical and meaningful.

Comment: _Worth_ is a very odd word; it's been variously called a noun and a preposition, and [it's got plenty of other odd features.](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf)

Comment: _Once the can is open, it is hard to put all the worms back in._ As John Lawler says. "**Worth** is a very odd word; it's been variously called a noun and a preposition, and it's got plenty of other odd features. –" Voting to re-open.

Comment: The dictionary says that _worth_ means **having a particular value**, not just _value_. So "What is it worth?" means "What value does it have?"

Comment: Grammatically, "worth" is an adjective in your example, more specifically it's one of just a handful of transitive adjectives. In "What is it worth" "It" is the subject, "is" the verb, and "what" and "worth" combine to form a predicative complement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the lexical class of the word 'worth' when used in a sentence like "Is this apple worth $3?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/what-is-the-lexical-class-of-the-word-worth-when-used-in-a-sentence-like-is-t) Or [What part of speech is worth?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83940/what-part-of-speech-is-worth)?

Comment: Fuzzy stuff again. The evidence points to "worth" being an adjective in the OP's example.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth:  Your example is similar to what is in my mind "What part OF speech is worth?". You have used "OF" and that's the point. So, I believe that "What is ITS worth" must be correct. Equivalently, one may say the ugly and strange sentence "What is the worth OF it?"

Comment: @Arash2020 the only thing wrong with "what is its worth" is that it sounds rather old fashioned; "what is its value" would be more likely today.  But the validity or correctness of "what is its worth" is not evidence of the invalidity or incorrectness of "what is it worth."  Both are correct, and the second is far more common in modern speech and writing.

Comment: @phoog: Thanks so much. If "what is its worth" is correct but old-fashioned, you have made my day.

Comment: @Arash2020 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+is+its+worth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3