# When can "very" modify a prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

In *Hamlet*, when Hammy Jr. asks Polonius whether a cloud looks like a whale, Polly replies,

> Very like a whale.

In contemporary English, however, "very like ..." feels ungrammatical. You instead have to epenthetically say "very much like ...".

Interestingly this restriction doesn't seem to apply to some similar constructions; I find the following all acceptable:

- "Very whale-like" (PP replaced with adjective)
- "Very similar to a whale" (synonymous phrasal preposition)
- "Really like a whale" (synonymous adverb)
- "Exactly like a whale", "Truly like a whale", "Somewhat like a whale" (different adverb)
- "Nothing like a whale" (adverb replaced with a word of arguable lexical class)
- "Very near a whale" (different preposition)
- Cerberus pointed out (in chat) that "That is so very like you" is also acceptable (different argument to preposition)

But these still unacceptable:

- *"Very by a whale", *"Very in a whale", *"Very inside a whale", *"Very toward a whale" (different preposition)

  - But "Directly by/in/inside/toward a whale" are fine.

**What determines whether "very" can modify a prepositional phrase?**

Comment: @tchrist: Then there was Jonah, who was very much into _a_ whale. :^)

Comment: If you check out the etymology of "very", it originally meant "truly" (cf. "vero" in Romance languages), so "Very like a whale" means something like "Truly like a whale" or "Really like a whale". But of course, as time flows, and people forget the original meaning, and just use what they heard other people saying, they may start considering only these expressions that they heard as "correct" and those that they're unfamiliar with as "incorrect", making rules out of thin air to explain their thinking if someone asks them for their reasons. Interesting question though.

Answer (score 9):

## “Very out of the way”

It is a bit tough to find cases of *very* modifying individual prepositions, but it is easy to find cases of *very* modifying entire prepositional phrases as a unit, just as it does other adjectives and adverbs.

- I think it’s very out of character for him.
- Things can be very out of place.
- Or very out of date.
- And very out of the way.
- They are very on top of music and very adamant about what they carry.
- I just really was very on the edge. Very on the edge, for a while.
- He’s very off his rocker today.
- She is really very behind the times, isn’t she?
- You’re not very with it today, are you?

Sometimes you can use it to mean “very much” or “very far”.

- Are you for Obama?  Yes, I’m a little bit for him, just not very for him.
- Are you against the draft?  Yes, I’m very against it.
- Is that over your head?  Yes, but not very over.
- Walk down the street past my house, but not very past it.
- If you can be more into something, you can be very into it. Is there anything you’re less into?
- No thank you, that whole scene is very beneath me.

At which point, the whilom preposition starts acting more adverbially, and adverbs can be veried without half so much trouble.  But some of the directional or adverbial ones really do seem to be modifiable by degree:

- Is the end near? Yes, I believe we’re very near the end now.
- Will the parade pass near here?  Yes, it will pass very near us. It shall pass very near, indeed.

---

## Being *very like* something

However, back to your main point about *very like something*.

I’m not sure that I’m willing to call *like* a preposition (the OED calls it an adjective for these sorts of uses), but here are assorted OED citations of “very like”:

> - 1719 De Foe *Crusoe* i. xᴠɪ, ― It was very like the Tree we call Fustic.
> - 1710 Swift *Jrnl. to Stella* 25 Oct., ― Addison’s sister is a sort of a wit, very like him.
> - 1727 A. Hamilton *New Acc. E. Ind.* II. xxxɪx. 81 ― The Durean is another excellent Fruit, but offensive to some Peoples Noses, for it smells very like human Excrements, but when once tasted the Smell vanishes.
> - 1868 Yates *Rock Ahead* II. 245 ― Wooded uplands suggested good cover-shooting; broad expanse of heath looked very like rabbits.
> - 1857 R. Tomes *Amer. in Japan* vi. 135 ― The jamana··is very like the red-wood of Brazil and Mexico.
> - 1865 *Pall Mall* G. 25 Oct. 10 ― Gladiateur’s colours are blue and red, and Nu’s are cerise (which is very like red) and blue.
> - 1836 Sir G. Head *Home Tour* 144 ― The town of Dewsbury··celebrated for··grinding old garments into new; literally tearing in pieces fusty old rags··by a machine called a ‘devil’, till a substance very like the original is reproduced.
> - 1926 F. Z. Snoop *Reproduction & Sexual Evolution* 83 ― Havelock Ellis quotes other cases, even butterflies (if insects may be here included) who possess excrescences on their penes, which of necessity must cause pain, or something very like pain, during coition.

And regarding your original Shakespearian citation, the OED notes that this has become (or was at one time) a set phrase, to be **very like a whale**:

> Allusive, proverbial, transf., and fig. uses of sense 1. a. Prov. phr. (***to throw out***) ***a tub to the whale***: see **tub** sb.<sup>9 b.</sup> ***very like a whale*** (after Shaks. Ham. ɪɪɪ. ii. 398): see quot. 1859.
>
> - 1591 1st Pt. Troub. Raigne K. John (1611) C 3 b, ― The mariner, Spying the hugie Whale, whose monstrous bulke Doth beare the waues like mountaines fore the wind, That throwes out emptie vessels, so to stay His fury.
> - 1859 Slang Dict. 115 ― *Very like a whale,* said of anything that is very improbable.

So in summary, I think that whatever you call *like*, there is no problem with things being ***very like*** other things.

Comment: Also from Shakespeare (*The Tempest*): *SEBASTIAN Ha, ha!
What things are these, my lord Antonio? Will money buy 'em? ANTONIO Very like. One of them Is a plain fish, and no doubt marketable.*

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Great examples and explanations, and a pithy, precise, and palatable summary.

Answer (score 4):

M-W.com says of this usage of *like*, which is an adjective and not a preposition:

> 3 like [adjective]
>
> 1a : the same or nearly the same (as in appearance, character, or quantity) [suits of like design] —formerly used with *as, unto, of*  [it behoved him to be made like unto his brethren — Heb 2:17 (Authorized Version)]
>
> 1b chiefly British : closely resembling the subject or original [the portrait is very like]

*Very like a whale* is perfectly grammatical in contemporary English. There's nothing wrong with it at all.

*Similar to* is **not a phrasal preposition**; it's an **adjective phrase** because, as stated above, *like* is an adjective and not a preposition. Grammatical terminology is not easy; it's often misunderstood and misused; and it's often disputed by different schools of linguistics. The names of parts of speech, however, are rarely disputed -- except, perhaps, for a few like *particle* and *adverb*. What is more important than the part-of-speech label, however, is the function of the word in the sentence.

Comment: But parts of speech are sometimes disputed, and this is a typically disputed area, I believe. See [What is the lexical class of the word 'worth' when used in a sentence like “Is this apple worth $3?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/what-is-the-lexical-class-of-the-word-worth-when-used-in-a-sentence-like-is-t).

Comment: @Cerberus: I agree that parts of speech are sometimes disputed, so I said "rarely disputed -- except...". I also don't trust _CGEL_ as far as I can throw it: like not very far. I don't find Huddleston & Pullum persuasive in their arguments, especially the _gave it to John and I_ argument. I found a web page that says: _Like is a preposition, like this example._ But I would argue that this is a solecism: it should be _...as in this example_". Because _very like a whale_ is a simile & means _very similar to a whale_, whatever part of speech _like_ is, its usage rules are unique?

Comment: Right, H&P certainly have their flaws. They make some (fairly arbitrary) choices and then proclaim all alternatives heretical. They also like changing and discarding conventional terms just for the heck of it. I think their introduction shows they have certain political motivations, like bashing style books.

Comment: @Cerberus: I enjoy bashing style books, especially the APA's. I don't think there's anything wrong with the idea of **a** style manual, just with the plethora that writers & editors have to deal with every day. If there were only one, we could all learn it by heart, know for certain what's "proper" **for publishing**, and not believe (as some do) that style books have anything to do with what's correct or grammatical or standard in everyday language.

Comment: @Cerberus: + 1 million

Comment: @user21497 I'm not sure that doesn't go against the First Amendment.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Modifying prepositional phrases with *very* needs degree meaning and is unusual**

The adverb *very* modifies expressions that can take on different **degrees**, i.e. whose semantics allow for a scale on which a concept can be compared. We can test for the presence of degrees with a paraphrase such as "to a certain degree." When a prepositional phrase allows for a degree interpretation, modification with *very* is marginally acceptable.

> (1) they are actually **very, very in love**. (2013, spoken English, NBC: Today Show)
>   (because paraphrase works: They are in love to a certain degree.)
>
> (2) * They are actually **very, very in London**.
>   (because paraphrase doesn't work: ??He is in London to a certain degree.)
>
> (3) I'm **very in favor** of more torpedoes. (2004, Bk: Wildfire, written English)
>   (because paraphrase works: I'm in favor of it to a certain degree.)
>
> (4) * I'm **very in front** of a torch.
>   (because paraphrase doesn't work: ??I'm in front of it to a certain degree.)
>
> (5) So, yes, I'm **very for it** (2002, CNN_Chung, spoken English)
>   (because paraphrase works: They support it to a certain degree.)
>
> (6) * I'm here **very for my colleague**
>   (because paraphrase doesn't work: ??I'm replacing my colleague to a certain degree.)

However, prepositional phrases are generally taken to express states. Speakers usually use them to convey an idea that can be true or false with no degrees in between. One is either in love or not, in London or somewhere else, for something or against something, etc. Therefore, *very* does not normally modify prepositional phrases.

To support this, I browsed the Corpus of Contemporary American English for five common prepositions, *in*, *on*, *of*, *for* and *about* and counted how often they are preceded by *very* in comparison to *very much*.  The results are shown below:

[image]
(***Figure 1***: use of *very* (vs. *very much*) + preposition in contemporary English)

The graph shows that prepositional phrases occur with *very* only very rarely, between 0.2% and 6.4%.

- **So, to answer the question: as a rule of thumb, *very* does not modify prepositional phrases, but it may sometimes do so if the prepositional phrase conveys a degree interpretation, rather than a true-or-false state.**

**(2) The preposition *like* is special – it derives from an adjective**

Originally, the word *like* functioned as an adjective in English. There are many ways to show this. Here are two adjectival characteristics that *like* used to possess.

(a) The word used to be inflected like any other adjective. For example, the following Old English example has the word *gelicestan*, literally *like-est* – the superlative of the adjective *like* ‘most like, most similar to.’

> (7) þa funde he oðerne [...] him þone ge**lic**estan,
>         then found he another one   him the     like-est
>   ‘He found then another one who was **most similar to him**’ 
>   (Old English *Bede*, 4:23, c. 880 A.D.)

(b) The adjective could also be nominalized. That means that you could turn the adjective into a noun just like you can turn *poor* or *blind* into a noun today (*The poor are suffering*, *The blind leading the blind*). The meaning would be something like ‘those who are like you, fellows, comrades’ (cf. *ilk*).

> (8) þine ge**lic**an
>            your  likes
>          ‘your companions’
>   (Aelfric’s *Life of Saint Eugenia*, c. 1000 A.D.)

Over time, the word *like* came to be distributed like prepositions. Again, there are many ways to demonstrate this, but I will only mention two arguments.

(a) As an adjective, *like* occurred almost exclusively with copula verbs, like *be*. But nowadays phrases with *like* can easily modify other verbs. Hence, expressions like *he swam like a fish*, *he worked like a maniac*, *she dressed like a princess* etc. used to be impossible but have now become quite common. One of the earliest examples of such modification I found, shown below, is from 1529. The OED (sense B.1.a(a)) lists the earliest date as c1390(a1376).

> (9) he dyd live **like a wyddower** / whiche a fore tyme had bene maryed
>   (Desiderius’ *An Exhortation to the Diligent Studye of Scripture*, 1529)

(b) The word *like* can now be used to introduce a list of typical examples, meaning ‘such as’. The OED (sense D.2(a)) records this usage from 1593 on.

> (10) i am acquainted with a sort of **men like him**
>   (Voiture’s *Letters of Affaires Love and Courtship*, 1657)

So, to summarize, the word *like* is slowly losing adjectival properties, such as adjectival inflection or nominalization, and slowly gaining prepositional uses, like verbal modification or listing of typical examples. Modification of *like* with *very* is just another of its adjectival features.

It follows that:

(i) Since *like* derives from, and retains some properties of, an adjective, modification with *very* is far more common for *like* than for any other preposition.
(ii) Since *like* is in a century-long process of losing its adjectival features, modification with *very* is slowly dropping out of use.

To demonstrate this, I collected some data from the Corpus of Historical American English. I compared the frequency of *very like* to *very much like* over time, as illustrated in the pairs of examples below.

> (11)a. Thou'rt **very like her**, that's certain (1822, LoganAFamilyHistory)
>   (11)b. that is **very much like him**. (1835, ClintonBradshaw)
>
> (12)a. being, in the shape of his body and limbs, **very like a frog** (1823, ErrataTheWorks)
>   (12)b. begin to feel myself **very much like a fish** out of water (1835, AnOldSailorsYarns)
>
> (13)a. you are **very like your father** (2006, Distraction)
>   (13)b. You look **very much like my son** at your age (2000, RulesSurrender)
>
> (14)a. He had her pale hair, a face **very like hers**. (2001, FantasySciFi)
>   (14)b. Mrs. Townsend or someone **very much like her**. (2004, Hallelujah!Welcome)

I also collected the same historical data for the preposition *in*. The graph below shows the percentage use of *very* (vs. *very much*) for every decade from 1810-2000.

[image]
(***Figure 2:*** Historical development of *very like* and *very in*)

As the graph shows, (i) modification with *very* occurs overwhelmingly more frequently for *like* than for other prepositions like *in*, by a factor of more than 20, and (ii) modification of *like* with *very* becomes less common over time, from 60-70% in the early 1800s to about 10-20% today.

- **Hence, there is a secondary answer to the question. The preposition *like* in particular is much more likely to permit modification with *very*, especially as you go further back in time, as in Shakespeare’s *very like a whale*, because *like* derives historically from an adjective.**

Comment: Sim­i­lar to Shake­speare’s use of *very like*, he also li­cenced *very worth* when in *Twelve Night* he had Vi­ola say: *“It may be worth thy pains, for I can sing / And speak to him in many sorts of mu­sic / That will al­low me **very worth** his ser­vice. / What else may hap, to time I will com­mit.”* It’s still not very grad­able in present-day English, for though I can marginally imag­ine some­thing be­ing *“more/most worth my while”*, its reg­u­lar in­flec­tions by de­gree (*⁕worther, ⁕worthest*) have been un­gram­mat­i­cal since the 18ᵗʰ cen­tury.

Answer (score 0):

*Very* is now normally used only to modify adjectives and adverbs, not verbs: it is not a normal adverb. Normal adverbs can modify verbs.

> You were *exactly* at the right place.
>
> You were **very* at the right place.

Here *exactly* modifies the verb *were*, you could say, or the predication *were at the right place*. *Very* cannot do this.

---

The word *like* was originally an adjective, and as such it could be modified by *very*, I believe, as in your *very like a whale*. It worked just like *worth*, with a postpositional object:

> The house is *worth* a ton.
>
> The house is *like* a ton.

This same construction survived up to the present time, obviously, but it is now not always felt to be a true adjective any more. It is rather felt to be a preposition in this construction (and a conjunction in *that's just like I did it*, which is still not accepted by everyone in formal writing). As a preposition, it usually does not admit of modification by *very*, just as *at the right place* above does not.

---

> Very *near* a whale

This sounds a bit unusual to me, which is probably because *near* went through a similar development from adjective to preposition.

> The *Near* East.
>
> God is *near*.

In these examples, *near* is used as an adjective.

> God is near the second cloud on your right.

Here as a preposition, or, if you want to look at it etymologically, as an adjective with a postpositional modifier (*the second cloud on your right*).

---

Prepositions are formed continually in all languages I know (which are admittedly all Indo-European), this is a natural process. It is said that prepositions were relatively new in Proto-Indo-European. They may even have formed only in later stages, as a convergent development in the later proto-languages. Our older prepositions do seem to originate in adverbs, not adjectives:

> That ball is out.
>
> That ball fell out.
>
> ? That out ball is interesting.

I would read the last sentence as a ball that was "out" in tennis or something, a fairly modern instance of ellipsis.

Comment: Seems to me that _near_  in  _God is **near**_  is a locative adverb. No difference between **near** and **here** in _God is **here**_. But **near** may be a subjective complement, but it doesn't modify God; it tells the reader/listener **where** God is, not that _God is **good/great/vindictive/invisible/green/dead** or any other adjective.

Comment: @BillFranke: I agree that you could look at it as adverbial; then again, it cannot be an adverb in other contexts, where it modifies a non-copular verb, so I would rather not call it an adverb here. I don't feel your last argument is very strong, though: a location can be a property to assign like any other. *God is approximate, God is remote, God is distant*. I would rather ascribe its adverbiality to the copula, or to its being a predicative adjective, as in *God was late*.

Comment: _Approximate, remote, distant_ are ADJ when describing God's personality or state-of-being traits and _remote & distant_ are locative ADV when describing position relative to me (e.g.). That, at least is my analysis. I don't claim to be infallible. I may be wrong. Unlike some usage mavens, I'm not an absolutist about language. Some things just don't fit nicely with the way we analyze the language. Usage is sometimes contradictory. BTW, I see _You were exactly at the right place_ as ungrammatical: should be _You were at exactly the right place_ in my idiolect. What works is best.

Comment: I agree that it is hard to use *very* to modify a verb, but getting it to do so for a preposition isn’t that hard. I guess you aren’t very into that kind of thing, though. :)

Comment: @BillFranke: *The distant clouds carried a promise of rain*. Here you can see *distant* used as a plain locative adjective. So there is nothing unusual about locative adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist: I would say that *very* modifies not the verb, but the phrase *into that kind of thing*. The idea is that *into that kind of thing* is used more or less as a fixed phrase and treated like an adjective. You will agree that it is informal.

Comment: @tchrist: No, you misunderstand. *Near* has an adjectival history, I believe, and hence it used to be modifiable by *very*, to some extent at least, which is unrelated to formality. But near ≠ regular preposition: that is exactly what my answer explained. If you use *very* before regular prepositions, on the other hand, it now sounds informal, as in *she is very into you*. That was the context. Then I said in my comment that *very* modifies not the verb, but the prepositional phrase *into you* in its capacity of a pseudo-adjective. That was my theory.

Answer (score 0):

First of, "like" in "very like a whale" is a preposition as attested by M-W Collegiate 11:

> Date: 13th century
>   1.a. : having the characteristics of : similar to  [his house is like a barn] [it's like when we were kids]

True! The same dictionary also lists "very" as an adjective as user21497 pointed out:

> 3 like [adjective] 1a : the same or nearly the same (as in appearance,
>   character, or quantity) [suits of like design] —formerly used with as,
>   unto, of  [it behoved him to be made like unto his brethren — Heb 2:17
>   (Authorized Version)]

I would argue that "like" being an adjective and meaning "(almost) identical" as in "like unto his brethren" does NOT make it less prepositional in "like a whale". I'm not saying that "adjective phrase" is the wrong take on this one, but that "unto" is the preposition in this case, which is comparable to "like (a whale)" or "(afraid) of".

---

ABOUT VERY LIKE

According to OED2, as an adverb, "very" is used for emphasis：
1. in a high degree 
2. with superlative or own used to emphasize that the following description applies without qualification

The second definition is not applicable to "very like a whale"). The first one is a working definition in the case of "very like a whale", suggesting a strong similarity between the cloud and a whale.

*"Very by a whale", *"Very in a whale", *"Very inside a whale", and *"Very toward a whale" do not sound right because "very" in the sense of "in a high degree" is not semantically viable in the aforementioned cases because:

you come either on a boat or by a whale;
you are either in/inside or out of/outside a whale's body;
you are either approaching (towards) or steering clear of the whale.

Yes, one might argue: doesn't "very" meaning in a large degree apply to the case where "I travelled 4/5 the journey by a whale"? No, because in that case, "majorly by a whale" or "mostly by a whale" would be appropriate. However, here and now, "majorly" or "mostly" modifies the verb--I mostly travelled by a whale because "mostly/majorly by a whale" in itself just won't work as I explained.

In short, where there is no "grey area", nor superlative (very best something), nor own (his very own car), you cannot use "very" as an adverb, and that's personally convincingly why we can't and don't say "He very ran."