# Can a PP be analysed as a complex adjective?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, prepositional-phrases, syntactic-analysis

In the sentence *They are more familiar with this*, the predicative complement *more familiar with this* is an AdjP, with the adjective head *familiar*. But what about a sentence such as *They are more at home with this*? Could *at home* be seen as a complex adjective here, despite its actual PP form? If not, how would we parse the predicative complement here (all levels)?

Comment: Related, maybe:  [When can “very” modify a prepositional phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83952)

Comment: No, not a complex adjective; rather, an idiomatic was of saying "at ease with". I'd say that "more" is a dependent of  "at home", where "at" is the head and "home" is its complement.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks!! But what would the form of the predicative complement as a whole be then?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot analyze one syntactic form as another one. Each grammatical form is defined by a set of criteria that makes it distinguishable from another one. So, a preposition cannot be an adjective, a noun cannot be a verb etc. Grammatical forms can be distributionally/functionally comparable or similar in certain syntactic contexts, but one cannot be the other. So, my general answer to the title question is no and never.

> They are ***more at home with this***.

The whole thing is an ascriptive predicative complement with the form of a prepositional phrase. 
There is a lot to say about this one. First, there is a number of prepositional phrases which are gradable (*completely in* control, *very much out* of sorts, *wholly out* of order etc. CGEL p643), typically functioning as the predicative complement. In the sentence at hand the adverb "more" modifies the following head PP "at home".

Which brings us to the interesting part. The head of a phrase doesn't have to be a word - it can be another phrase. This is the case here. The head of the PP "more at home with this" is another PP - *"at home"*. The PP *"with this"* is a complement of the head PP "at home".

The authors of CGEL say "..one PP can function within a larger one, as head, complement, or modifier" (p646), which is followed by sentences illustrating each use.

Comment: Yes; I'm not anti-CGEL per se, far from it. Though I prefer the splitting off of the set of _prepositional-phrase-modifiers_ (I'll add the examples _just_ behind the door, _rather_ under the weather, _right_ into the middle of the hole) from the adverb ragbag.

Comment: @Edwin  Directional prepositional modifiers are even more common than adverbial ones: look UP into the sky, put it BACK on the shelf etc.

Comment: I'd not class those as PP modification; the adverbs here don't modify the PP but rather the verb. 'Look [up] [into the sky]' but 'She putted it [right into the middle of the hole]'.

Comment: @Edwin Good point! I've checked CGEL, p645 for examples and the authors would clearly parse the latter sentence as I put it [back on the shelf] (as opposed to "I put it [back] [on the shelf] . The same would go for your example of course: She putted it [back into the hole] . The adverb "right" and the directional preposition "back" would be analyzed the same then. I'd also be tempted to  parse the "look up into the sky" as you did, and I wouldn't mind analyzing the other one the same, as : I looked [up] [into the sky].

Comment: Off the top of my head, I could come up with a lot of (with a non-literal interpretation of the preposition) examples where the test they offer fails to prove anything (including the previous sentence: I came with a lot of .. won't do) . But then, there are no intransitive examples among those on p645, so let's take a similar one(also non-literal meaning) : I put it down to his stressful job. (Clearly, the interpretation in this one doesn't depend on the PP "to his stressful job" ) What should this implicate is a question that will take me more thinking :)

Comment: I took just a quick glance at the page, I might go back to it later and see if there is more to it than how I understood it. It may not be possible to draw definitive conclusions about this question from what they said on this point in CGEL.

Comment: The starting point 'definitive conclusions [about a correct grammatical model] from what [they] say' seems to cut across the idea of the scientific method. Who decides when the best interpretation has finally been arrived at? How?

Comment: The one that is logically unassailable within the proposed grammatical model is going to take the cake :) Actually, people who aspire to be good linguists have to learn logic. I haven't and I won't but I understand why logic matters in language.

Comment: 'The one that is logically unassailable within the proposed grammatical model is going to take the cake' is demonstrably false. The definition of 'idiom' is 'a construction containing an irregular/non-standard sense of a word, irregular/non-standard grammar, or both'.

Comment: Okay, the model which is logically the most consistent will be the one that will be most widely accepted.

Comment: The bogus-ditransitive (actually misconstrued as an actual ditransitive construction by one authority) 'He led her a merry dance' is vastly preferred over the logical 'He led her in a merry dance' (and 'He led her up the garden path in what might be termed a merry dance' etc). I have a list of extra-grammatical idioms (one term that has been used is 'non-grammatical', but usage eventually trumps standard grammar (and logic) where there is a conflict. 'More than one of them was killed' (an example of grammatical illogicality, highlighted by CS Lewis).