# Is 'It worths mentioning' correct?

Tags: grammar

Just wondering whether `It worths mentioning` is grammatically correct? If not, what's the correct way to say that?

Comment: *Worth* [is an adjective](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worth) not a verb, so cannot be *worths.* This means that the [related question in the sidebar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/which-is-correct-is-it-worth-it-or-does-it-worth-it?rq=1) is relevant: it cannot be "does it worth mentioning", so it must be "is it worth mentioning" and therefore "It is worth mentioning."

Comment: Often when I think something is worth mentioning, I mention it, as now. However, I see it as wasting the reader's time to delay things by saying *It's worth mentioning that...*, which adds no value. Otherwise this comment becomes "It's worth mentioning that the phrase *It's worth mentioning* isn't."

Comment: The grammatical category that _worth_ belongs to is a matter of some dispute, [as discussed here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83946/15299).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is incorrect. Ask yourself this question: What is "It" doing to "mentioning"? Well obviously it's not doing anything, but that construction makes it sound like "worths" is the verb connecting "It" with "mentioning". The grammatically appropriate alternative is "It is worth mentioning."